# graphql why do I need to declare a extra parameter within a resolvers parameter

Tags: javascript, express, graphql, apollo-server, express-graphql

I had been reading everywhere about graphql and was stuck in a misunderstand implementation in the resolvers function:

This was my bad resolver, what I was getting was a undefined argument:

```
const jobResolvers = {
   Query: {
     job(id) {
       //code where I call the db ODM function
     }
   }
 }
```

After looking a few post I fix it:
**(understand the destructor part, but not why the underscore _ paremeter )**

```
const jobResolvers = {
  Query: {
    job(_,{id}) {
      //code where I call the db ODM function
     }
   }
 }
```

Here you can see this two very good and explanatory post **bad luck they don't explain, why are they two parameters in a resolver function**(**This is the big question**)

- the implementation of graphql server side
  [getAuthor(_,{id})](https://dev-blog.apollodata.com/graphql-explained-5844742f195e) the signature of the function have two parameters but only the second one is use and it will not work with only the *id* parameter
- the other about GraphQL explained (*How does a GraphQL server turn a query into a response?*)
  [author(root, args)](https://dev-blog.apollodata.com/tutorial-building-a-graphql-server-cddaa023c035?_ga=2.121665035.1071215027.1519942123-1372050369.1516617867) the signature of the function have two parameters but only use the second one also the function will not work with only *args* parameter(**root never work for me**)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GraphQL resolvers have a specific function signature. `resolver(obj, args, context)` You want to use `args`, so you need to pad `obj` so that args are passed properly. Generally people use `_` to signify a param that people don't need but has to be there to satisfy the signature.

http://graphql.org/learn/execution/#root-fields-resolvers